# How to map a list of key/values to a space separated list of keyValue=valueValue entries in jq?

Tags: json, jq

How can I transform this output:

```
$ jq -s '.[0] * .[1] * .[2] | to_entries' a.json b.json c.json
[
  {
    "key" : "SimpleNumber",
    "value" : "123"
  },
  {
    "key" : "SimpleString",
    "value" : "Hello"
  },
  {
    "key" : "ComplexString",
    "value" : "Hello World"
  }
]
```

to:

1)

```
"SimpleNumber=123" "SimpleString=Hello" "ComplexString=Hello World"
```

and

2)

```
SimpleNumber="123" SimpleString="Hello" ComplexString="Hello World"
```

Comment: You want the output as a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Stringinterpolation-%5C(foo)) combined with [`join()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#join(str)):

```
jq --raw-output 'map("\"\(join("="))\"") | join(" ")'
```

to generate

```
"SimpleNumber=123" "SimpleString=Hello" "ComplexString=Hello World"
```

[Try it online](https://jqplay.org/s/4KziA3nZll)

---

Or to it 'by hand' to quote only the value:

```
jq --raw-output 'map("\(.key)=\"\(.value)\"") | join(" ")'
```

```
SimpleNumber="123" SimpleString="Hello" ComplexString="Hello World"
```

[Try it online](https://jqplay.org/s/4hQi15uxC3)

Comment: You may want to correct your link to [String interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Stringinterpolation-%5C(foo)).

Comment: I just can't get it to work with the backslash. It becomes escaped in the preview, thats working fine, but when I save it. The (escaped) backslash is gone...

Comment: I changed it for you.

Comment: Yea hard code escape works, didn't think of that. Still not sure why that didn't work. thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use string interpolation and put the quotes as you see fit:

1. around whole items

```sh
jq -r 'map("\"\(.key)=\(.value)\"") | join(" ")'
```

```
"SimpleNumber=123" "SimpleString=Hello" "ComplexString=Hello World"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/76sJeRhG2M)

2. just around the "value"

```sh
jq -r 'map("\(.key)=\"\(.value)\"") | join(" ")'
```

```
SimpleNumber="123" SimpleString="Hello" ComplexString="Hello World"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4hQi15uxC3)